# When I go to use the letters C, A or the directional pad it doesn't work

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++ when I use the <kbd>C</kbd> key a box appears that has the title "Column/multi-selection editor". I was using Notepad++ yesterday but now when I want to type "class", it doesn't work, but when I got to Google or anywhere else my <kbd>C</kbd> key works.

My <kbd>A</kbd> key just doesn't work but everywhere else it does; the same with my directional pad.

Answer (score 0):

#### When I go to use the letters <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd> or the directional pad it doesn't work

The normal shortcut for the "Column/multi-selection editor" is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *not* <kbd>C</kbd>.

There are no shortcut attached to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Conclusion:

Your keyboard has got into a strange state and thinks the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key has been pressed (and not released).

Normally when this happens pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> several times then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> several times then <kbd>Shift</kbd> several times returns the keyboard to a normal state.

You should also check your settings for [Stick Keys](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-xp/help/using-stickykeys).